# Download legit copy of Fifa 16 without activation key

Tags: origin, fifa-16

I purchased a Fifa 16 key from an online seller, but haven't got a copy of Fifa 16.

Is there any way to download Fifa 16 from origin without paying for the key, again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "Origin" you mean the EA digital distribution client, you can just right-click the icon in your task tray, select "redeem product code" and then activate the key in there.

If you don't have the client, you can download it from https://www.origin.com/en-us/download. You'll need a free EA account to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am actually about to order the activation code that's why  wanted to confirm one thing. After entering the code in redeem section, will it let me download the game copy for free?

Comment: @H_Z yes, and you'll be able to for as long as Origin stays a thing, even if you get a new PC. you just need to keep your account secure. Note that if you ever lose access to your account, be it through a ban or because someone stole it, you also lose access to the games on that account.